# How can I access boot disk from google cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-instances

My google cloud instance got a problem and it's preventing me to access the ssh. I would like to access the boot disk image from gcloud shell to download my files. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to recover data from your existing boot disk of the problematic VM instance, you can detach the boot disk and then attach that disk as a secondary disk on a new instance so that you can have access to the data.

1. [Detach the boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) from the existing VM instance by running the following command.

   ```
   gcloud compute instances detach-disk [INSTANCE_NAME] --disk=my-disk
   ```
2. Create a new VM and attach the old VM's boot disk as secondary disk by running the following command.

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create [NEW_VM_NAME] --disk name=BOOT_DISK_NAME,boot=yes,auto-delete=no
   ```
3. Connect to your new VM using SSH:

   ```
     gcloud compute ssh [NEW_VM_NAME]
   ```

Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#common_ssh_errors) that describes common errors that you may run into, when connecting to virtual machine (VM) instances using SSH, also ways to resolve errors for diagnosing failed SSH connections.

Comment: If the original boot disk is broken, the new instance will not boot. Instead, I recommend detaching the boot disk instead of deleting the instance and then attaching the boot disk as a second disk drive to a new instance. **gcloud compute instances detach-disk ... **

Comment: thank you for your answers. I followed your steps and successfully retrieved my data. Thank You

Comment: Hello @Kaidolex, Glad to hear that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it (✔️) for the benifit of other community members who may face the same issue. I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new VM with a brand new disk. Add the problematic boot disk as additional disk. Start your new VM, log into it, and browse the additional disk to get your files.